# Cannot find JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try
        {
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "";
            //<facility> is my database
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/facility";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Cannot connect to database server " +e.getClass().getName());

        }
```

***output> Cannot connect to database server java.lang.ClassNotFoundException***

Comment: Can you make sure that your jdbc driver jar file is in classpath.  Usually its mysql-connector-java.<version>.jar

Comment: This means you don't have the JDBC jar into your classpath. You can get it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Comment: Instead of just printing out the name of the exception print out the message or the entire stack trace.

Comment: In your error message, I'd suggest doing an e.printStackTrace instead of just printing the class. A comment you made on one of the answers indicates that you have the Driver jar in your classpath, so perhaps there is some other info we can glean from a larger stacktrace

Comment: The driver is the error :) Joahann du Toit below answered the question. Now it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you should put your MySQL driver jar into your **classpath**.

Comment: I have included to build path Connector/J which i found here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Answer (score 2):

To use the MYSQL Driver (Connector/J) you will need to download it from [MySQL Connectors](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) and put it in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Download the jdbc-mysql driver [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Include it in your classpath.